# jQuery $.grep returning empty JSON

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to get certain classes based off their `id` from the database on the server side. The data sent from the server is in JSON format. The following is the JSON I am currently working with:

```
var classes = {
  "success": true,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "mechanics",
      "created_at": "2016-08-08T15:37:14"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "mechanics",
      "created_at": "2011-10-02T23:25:42"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Stephen's Rad New Course",
      "created_at": "2016-09-07T15:44:50"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "English",
      "created_at": "2016-10-28T07:09:45"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "Mathematics",
      "created_at": "2017-02-15T13:33:49"
    }
  ]
}
```

The `id` that I am using is taken from another JSON:

```
var student = {
  "success": true,
  "data": {
    "privileges": [
      {
        "type": "mac"
      },
      {
        "type": "scones"
      }
    ],
    "fname": "Luke",
    "loaned": [],
    "classes": [
      {
        "name": "Stephen's Rad New Course",
        "id": 4,
        "created_at": "2016-09-07T15:44:50"
      },
      {
        "name": "Mathematics",
        "id": 6,
        "created_at": "2017-02-15T13:33:49"
      }
    ],
    "type": "student",
    "created_at": "2016-08-24T09:35:26",
    "lname": "Skywalker",
    "id": 44,
    "email": "skywalker.ftw@cedarhouse.co.za"
  }
}
```

Here is the code I am using to filter the data:

```
for (var j = 0; j < student.data.classes.length; j++) {
    var class_id = student.data.classes[j].id;
    classes = $.grep(classes, function(n, i) {
        return n.id == class_id;
    });
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(classes));
```

Based off the classes that that goes with the student JSON data, only those two classes with IDs of 4 and 6 should be displayed but right now nothing is being displayed.

Comment: [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a non-array `classes` to `$.grep` (you probably intended `classes.data`), and you are overwriting the previous assignment to `classes` by the next in every iteration of the loop.

Instead, gather the `id` values in an array, and then filter for those `id`s that are in that array with `Array#indexOf` (or `Array#includes` in modern browsers):

```
var class_ids = student.data.classes.map(function (cls) {
    return cls.id;
});

classes.data = classes.data.filter(function(n) {
    return class_ids.indexOf(n.id) > -1;
});
console.log(classes);
```

```js
var classes = {
  "success": true,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "mechanics",
      "created_at": "2016-08-08T15:37:14"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "mechanics",
      "created_at": "2011-10-02T23:25:42"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Stephen's Rad New Course",
      "created_at": "2016-09-07T15:44:50"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "English",
      "created_at": "2016-10-28T07:09:45"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "Mathematics",
      "created_at": "2017-02-15T13:33:49"
    }
  ]
}

var student = {
  "success": true,
  "data": {
    "privileges": [
      {
        "type": "mac"
      },
      {
        "type": "scones"
      }
    ],
    "fname": "Luke",
    "loaned": [],
    "classes": [
      {
        "name": "Stephen's Rad New Course",
        "id": 4,
        "created_at": "2016-09-07T15:44:50"
      },
      {
        "name": "Mathematics",
        "id": 6,
        "created_at": "2017-02-15T13:33:49"
      }
    ],
    "type": "student",
    "created_at": "2016-08-24T09:35:26",
    "lname": "Skywalker",
    "id": 44,
    "email": "skywalker.ftw@cedarhouse.co.za"
  }
}

var class_ids = student.data.classes.map(function (cls) {
    return cls.id;
});

classes.data = classes.data.filter(function(n) {
    return class_ids.indexOf(n.id) > -1;
});
console.log(classes);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Unless you are working with very outdated browsers, there is no need to use jQuery for this.

Comment: Oh wow! I like how clean that code looks compared to my mess haha. How would I approach the opposite of what I am doing though? By opposite, I mean to find classes that isn't the ID of 4 and 6. I used `grep` here and it works.

Comment: then you do `indexOf(n.id) === -1`.